# Can run multiple OS command using variable in Python?

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Hello I'm trying to run multiple OS command using Python in Mac OS

I want to convert image to tif file by using convert command in Terminal. However I have 100 images to convert, I make Python program to make it easier.

```
import os
import subprocess

files = os.listdir("/Users/woonie/Downloads/test")

i=1
for file in files:
    args=['convert',file,'-resize','100%','-type',"Grayscale","/Users/woonie/Downloads/test/kor.",i,"test.exp0.tif"]
    subprocess.Popen(args)
    i = i+1
```

convert filename -...- output_filename.exp0.tif is the form of convert command so I need to change file name and output_filename every time. I have filename list in files. And I want to put number of image after "test" so it becomes kor.test1.exp0.tif, kor.test2.exp0.tif, etc.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/woonie/PycharmProjects/image_chage/change.py", line 9, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen(args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1637, in _execute_child
    self.pid = _posixsubprocess.fork_exec(
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int
```

But this error came out.

So I have changed that code to

```
args=['convert'+str(file)+'-resize','100%','-type',"Grayscale","/Users/woonie/Downloads/test/kor."+str(i)+"test.exp0.tif"]
```

But same error came out... 
It was work when I put that command directly into Terminal.

Did I use subprocess wrong? or I can't make program what I want to

Comment: Are you sure this is your real code?  `args=['convert'+str(file)+'-resize'` would produce `convertFILENAME-resize` as the first arg, which wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes it's my code. Then should I write it down it shout ','?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
subprocess.run(args)
```

instead of

```
subprocess.Popen(args)
```

That being said, your `args` array should probably look like

```
args=['convert', str(file), '-resize','100%','-type',"Grayscale","/Users/woonie/Downloads/test/kor."+str(i)+"test.exp0.tif"]
```

because the filename and the resize options are probably separate arguments.

Comment: Thanks I think your answer was helpful. But sadly I have new error

Comment: convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562.
convert: no images defined `/Users/woonie/Downloads/test/kor.test1.exp0.tif' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3282. ... etc

Comment: @Meteor정 That one is an ImageMagick error, ask another qestion about IM. Note that [ImageMagick has a Python API](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ImageMagick)...

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with your code.

---

Rather than carry around long pathnames multi-levels deep in your input and output files, it is often better to just change directory to where the files are and deal with simple filenames - it is less error-prone and less of a maintenance nightmare.

So, consider starting your code with something more like:

```
import os

# Go to where the images are
os.chdir('/Users/woonie/Downloads/test')
```

---

Rather than use use `os.listdir()`, you get much more flexibility if you use globbing exactly the same as you would in the shell. So, if you want to process just JPEGs rather than TIFFs you produced on the previous run, use:

```
import glob

# Get list of JPEGs to process
JPEGs = glob.glob('*jpg')
```

---

I am unsure why you are using `subprocess.Popen()` - you would normally do that when you want to capture the output, you might as well use `subprocess.run()`

---

I don't know why you use `-resize 100%`. Where did that come from? The image should be 100% anyway.

---

When you want to formulate your output filename, you can more simply use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#simple-syntax). So, having got rid of all the long paths, your last parameter becomes:

```
f'kor.{i}test.exp0.tif'
```